# fix Line is too long error in a ruby file

Tags: ruby, rubocop

how to fix Line is too long error in a ruby file without ignoring it and not introducing new errors.
I have tried giving the extra character in the next line using IDE. It is introducing new errors like 'Ternary operators must not be nested. Prefer if or else constructs instead.'

Comment: Prefer if or else constructs instead.

Answer (score 1):

Rubocop already suggested the way to fix this error. Let me repeat it here. Assuming you have a very long line that reads:

```
variable = long_condition ? true_clause : false_clause
```

change it to:

```
variable = if long_condition
             true_clause
           else
             false_clause
           end
```

Other way would be to instruct `rubocop` to [temporary] ignore this error by running from the very project directory:

```
rubocop --auto-gen-config
```

Or, as last but not the least chance, update your `.rubocop.yml` file to increase a line length within a respective rule.

Answer (score 0):

Rubocop tells you what to do, just follow its advice.

Also, have a look at the [ruby styleguide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide), which explains all the rubocop rules in detail.